# Using Spring components in tests

Tags: java, spring

I have a class that looks roughly like this:

```
@Component
public class MyService {
    private MyBean myBean;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(MyBean myBean) {
        this.myBean = myBean;
    }
}
```

I would like to test this class. It would be nice if I could get it to autowire in my tests using a test MyBean object. I tried doing this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public MyBean myBean() {
            return createMock(myBean);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run my tests I get an error like:

`Injection of autowired dependencies failed`
`No matching bean of type MyService found for dependency: expected at least one bean that is a candidate for this dependency`.

How can I tell spring to look for my component so it knows how to autowire it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable component scan

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { MyServicePackage })
static class ContextConfiguration  {
...
```